# calling a model twice causes memory error

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am using the following format in a training procedure.

```
output1= model(input, mode=‘a’)
loss1= loss_fun1(output1)
output2=model(input, mode=‘b’)
loss2=loss_fun2(output2)
total_loss = loss1+loss2
optimizer.zero_grad()
total_loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Now, the problem is I am getting a memory error when I am calling the model twice. Again, if use torch.no_grad() for the mode ‘b’, I am breaking the computational graph and, I cannot do that. Is there any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by "memory error" you mean "out of memory": your model works fine when you pass `input` through it once and call `backward`, but there is not enough available memory to store two graphs.

It depends on how your `model` is implemented. If there are no intermediate tensors reused between modes `a` and `b`, you can process two graphs separately, retaining only partial gradients for the weights, and it will be mathematically equivalent to your original algorithm.

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
output1 = model(input, mode=‘a’)
loss1 = loss_fun1(output1)
loss1.backward()
output2 = model(input, mode=‘b’)
loss2 = loss_fun2(output2)
loss2.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I meant an 'out of memory' error. However, I still face the same problem.

Comment: @user491683, Please add relevant details to your question. It's still unclear whether there is sufficient memory to train using only a single mode. Show what you tried, what solutions you've considered but can't use. There are dozens of things that might help someone with a similar problem description.